# Google Sign In Using Firebase UI

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebaseui

I get the following error whenever I try to Sign In Using Google. I am using the Firebase UI.

"Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab."

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't yet set up your own web URL as an <kbd>Authorized Domain</kbd> in the Firebase console panel for [Authorized domains](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers)
.

[image]